# EKS Fargate coreDns pod in pending state

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, coredns

I have created a eks cluster with Fargate profile in private subnet. After that I have patched coredns with Fargate annotation but coredns pod is still in pending state after issuing this below command and restarting

```
kubectl patch deployment coredns \
    -n kube-system \
    --type json \
    -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1compute-type"}]'
```

Terraform config
cluster.tf

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {

  name                      = var.cluster_name
  role_arn                  = var.cluster_role
  version                   = var.cluster_version
  enabled_cluster_log_types = var.cluster_enabled_log_types

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids      = compact(distinct(concat(var.cluster_additional_security_group_ids, [var.cluster_security_group_id])))
    subnet_ids              = coalescelist(var.control_plane_subnet_ids, var.subnet_ids)
    endpoint_private_access = var.cluster_endpoint_private_access
    endpoint_public_access  = var.cluster_endpoint_public_access
    public_access_cidrs     = var.cluster_endpoint_public_access_cidrs
  }

  kubernetes_network_config {
    ip_family         = var.cluster_ip_family
    service_ipv4_cidr = var.cluster_service_ipv4_cidr
  }
  
  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    var.cluster_tags,
  )
}
```

Fargate profile

```
resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "eks_fargate" {
  count = var.create ? 1 : 0

  cluster_name           = var.cluster_name
  fargate_profile_name   = var.fargate_profile_name
  pod_execution_role_arn = var.iam_role_arn
  subnet_ids             = var.subnet_ids

  selector {
    namespace = var.selectors
  }

  dynamic "timeouts" {
    for_each = [var.timeouts]
    content {
      create = lookup(var.timeouts, "create", null)
      delete = lookup(var.timeouts, "delete", null)
    }
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

Coredns pod details

```
Name:                 coredns-78dcd9fb45-tv6vn
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Service Account:      coredns
Node:                 <none>
Labels:               eks.amazonaws.com/component=coredns
                      eks.amazonaws.com/fargate-profile=hds-fargate-profile
                      k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=78dcd9fb45
Annotations:          CapacityProvisioned: 0.25vCPU 0.5GB
                      Logging: LoggingDisabled: LOGGING_CONFIGMAP_NOT_FOUND
                      eks.amazonaws.com/compute-type: fargate
                      kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-11-21T14:10:45+05:30
                      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:               Pending
IP:                   
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/coredns-78dcd9fb45
NominatedNodeName:    5367f7aa1d-a9be6cbb0883413ca6cc82f2aa194a17
Containers:
  coredns:
    Image:       602401143452.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.7-eksbuild.1
    Ports:       53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8080/health delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /tmp from tmp (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-9ldq9 (ro)
Volumes:
  tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-9ldq9:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  LoggingDisabled   32m   fargate-scheduler  Disabled logging because aws-logging configmap was not found. configmap "aws-logging" not found
  Warning  FailedScheduling  29m   fargate-scheduler  Pod provisioning timed out (will retry) for pod: kube-system/coredns-78dcd9fb45-tv6vn
  Warning  FailedScheduling  26m   fargate-scheduler  Pod provisioning timed out (will retry) for pod: kube-system/coredns-78dcd9fb45-tv6vn
  Warning  LoggingDisabled   26m   fargate-scheduler  Disabled logging because aws-logging configmap was not found. configmap "aws-logging" not found
  Warning  FailedScheduling  23m   fargate-scheduler  Pod provisioning timed out (will retry) for pod: kube-system/coredns-78dcd9fb45-tv6vn
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: afaik aws_eks_cluster is for non-fargate clusters.

Comment: This thread may help you resolve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76634577/12523380

Answer (score 0):

Deleting nodeAffinity section helped me:

```
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/os
            operator: In
            values:
            - linux
          - key: kubernetes.io/arch
            operator: In
            values:
            - amd64
            - arm64
```